# System.listException while inserting data into account

Tags: trigger

i have written a trigger on account to create contact automatically but it is working fine in the case of updating only,while inserting in account  i am getting the following error
this is my code:

```
trigger ContactsupdateAccountphone on Account (after insert,after update) {
    contact con=new contact ();
    list<contact> conlist=new list<contact>();

    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert ){

        for(account acc1:trigger.new){
            con.accountid=acc1.id;
            con.lastname=acc1.name;
            con.phone=acc1.phone; 
            conlist.add(con);
        }
        if(conlist != null && conlist.size()>0){
        insert conlist;
     }
    map<id,account> mapac=new map<id,account>();
    set<id> setac=new set <id>();  
    for(account a:trigger.new){
        setac.add(a.id);
        mapac.put(a.id,a);
    }
    list<contact> lcon=[select id,lastname,phone,accountid from contact where accountid =: setac];
    for(contact c:lcon){
        if(mapac.containsKey(c.accountid)){
            c.LastName=mapac.get(c.accountid).name;
            c.Phone=mapac.get(c.AccountId).phone;
            c.AccountId=mapac.get(c.AccountId).id;
        }
        conlist.add(c);  
    }
    system.debug('The trigger.Old value '+trigger.Old);
    system.debug('The trigger.new value '+trigger.new);
    system.debug('The trigger.Oldmap value '+trigger.Oldmap);
    system.debug('The trigger.newmap value '+trigger.newmap);
    if(conlist != null && conlist.size()>0){
        update conlist;
    }
}
}
```

this is my error:

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger ContactsupdateAccountphone caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: ContactsupdateAccountphone:
>   execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id
>   in list: 0032800000DpHmuAAF: Trigger.ContactsupdateAccountphone: line
>   36, column 1

Comment: from line `map<id,account> mapac=new map<id,account>();`  to below all code  . wrap inside if condition `if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isUpdate )`

Comment: N.B. `if(conlist != null && conlist.size()>0)` is unnecessary; if list is empty, DML does nothing

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid duplicate Id errors by using `Map<Id, SObject>` instead.

```
Map<Id, Contact> insertedContacts = new Map<Id, Contact>(/*records*/);
insertedContacts.put(alreadyMappedContact.Id, alreadyMappedContact);
update insertedContacts.values();
```